# How to resolve Mysql Near Sintax Error CI

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hello guys I want to ask, Im Develop some application with CI 3, i have build own model like this but some error with mysql syntax ,how to resolve this, or my sql query was wrong ?

```
function get_ref_bidang()
{
    $this->db->select("CAST(A.Kd_Urusan AS varchar(2))+'.'+RIGHT('0' + CAST(A.Kd_Bidang AS varchar(2)),2) AS Kd_Bidang_Gab");
    $this->db->select("CAST(A.Kd_Urusan AS varchar(2))+'.'+CAST(A.Kd_Bidang AS varchar(2)) +' - '+ A.Nm_Bidang AS Nm_Bidang_Gab");
    $this->db->from("Ref_Bidang A");
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Thanks For Your help..Thanks

Comment: `syntax error` not `sintax error` ... ironically this in itself is a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use addition (`+`) on strings.  That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, thats right..im trying to add (.) dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function inasted of `+`

Mysql didn't support `CAST`  varchar datatype that you can [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) data to `char`

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(CAST(A.Kd_Urusan AS char(2)),'.',RIGHT(CONCAT('0',CAST(A.Kd_Bidang AS char(2))),2)) AS Kd_Bidang_Gab");
$this->db->select("CONCAT(CAST(A.Kd_Urusan AS char(2)),'.',CAST(A.Kd_Bidang AS char(2)) ,' - ', A.Nm_Bidang) AS Nm_Bidang_Gab");
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZoxneME6aRU39qCTyLUze/0)

Comment: its same errorcheck the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(2)), '.', RIGHT(CONCAT('0',

Comment: Its Works... Thanks, btw CAST cant convert to Varchar ? @d-shih

Comment: @Coby Because Mysql didn't support `CAST` varchar

Comment: can you help me ones question again ? about sql syntax ?